# Expanding group by window to count nunique

Tags: pandas, window, pandas-groupby

I have the following df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'month':[1]*4+[2]*4+[3]*4,'customer':[1,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,2,3,10,7]})
```

I want to create an expanding window to count number of unique customers at any point.
the output for the following df should be:

```
{1:4,2:7,3:8}
```

because in the first month we had 4 different customers, in the 2nd one, 3 where added (the other one was in the first month, and in the last month only one added (number 10))

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first drop the duplicated customers (only keep the first ones that appeared) and then cumulatively sum the number of (now unique) customers per month:

```
counts = df.drop_duplicates("customer").groupby("month").size().cumsum().to_dict()
```

to get

```
>>> counts

{1: 4, 2: 7, 3: 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are repeated customers, you can drop those repeated customers using

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='customer',ignore_index=True,inplace=True)
```

By default it will keep the first occurence of customer number and will drop next occurences. To count the number of unique customers each month,

```
df['customer'] = df.groupby('month')['customer'].transform('count')
df = df.drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
```

To roll the window over the `customer` column, calculate cumulative sum of that column

```
df['customer'] = df['customer'].cumsum()
```

It will give the desired output

```
month   customers
  1        4
  2        7
  3        8
```